# Facebook OGP not working correctly

Tags: facebook, image, sharing

I'm trying to show a thumbnail when a link to my site is shared on Facebook but it's not working properly. I have tried using the Facebook object debugger and I get the following warnings:

```
The og:url property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
The og:title property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
```

These are the meta tags I'm using:

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="227018187387679" />
<meta property="og:locale" content="en_US" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Tree Removal Gone Wrong" />
<meta property="og:type" content="video.other" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.asopao.com/video/2611" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.asopao.com/media/videos/tmb/2611/1.jpg" />
```

The URL is http://asopao.com/video/2611/tree-removal-gone-wrong

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the linter:
http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fasopao.com%2Fvideo%2F2611%2Ftree-removal-gone-wrong

You're missing those tags.

Here's exactly what your server is sending to facebook:

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/echo?q=http%3A%2F%2Fasopao.com%2Fvideo%2F2611%2Ftree-removal-gone-wrong

These are the only meta tags you're sending.

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />

<meta name="robots" content="noodp, noydir" />

<meta name="description" content=" Facebook is a social utility that connects people with friends and others who work, study and live around them. People use Facebook to keep up with friends, upload an unlimited number of photos, post links and videos, and learn more about the people they meet." />
```

Comment: But if you look at the source on http://asopao.com/video/2611/tree-removal-gone-wrong you can see the tags there.

Comment: I don't see them.  I have javascript turned off just like the linter does.

Comment: No it didnt. It still doesn't work even though i have checked and double checked the meta tags.

Comment: It's because you still have not put in the correct tags onto the page.  I just viewed source and dont see any.  Can you please post the source where you see the og tags specified correctly, because I do not see it.

Comment: http://asopao.com/video/1458/la-ley-mentira-hd line 5-12. I'm 10000% sure they are showing up in my browser.

Comment: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fasopao.com%2Fvideo%2F1458%2Fla-ley-mentira-hd  AS you can see, Facebook is still not able to grab that information.   Why don't you use a user agent switcher and change to the user agent of facebook and try seeing what your server is responding with.